# What are the correct /wp-content folder permissions to upload file by filezilla and php(wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I have aws EC2 and I installed WordPress, I am unable to upload a file from FTP and wordpress, one at a time works.

**Scenario 1**:if i change 'var/www/html' folders permissions to 755 and owner as ubuntu:ubuntu then i can upload using filezilla but not from wordpress.wordpress shows 'unable to move file '`/wp-content/uploads`

**Scenario 2** :if i change owner to `www-data:www-data` then can upload from WordPress but not from FileZilla. It shows error open for write: permission denied

I have used following commands for FileZilla to work:

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu: ubuntu /var/www/lifestyledesignpros.com/
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/lifestyledesignpros.com/public_html/wp-content/
```

With this FileZilla can upload, but WordPress not so I used following to WordPress to work:

```
sudo chown -R data:www-data /var/www/lifestyledesignpros.com/
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/lifestyledesignpros.com/public_html/wp-content/
```

**Question** What permission,/owner should I configure to `../wp-content/`so both FTP and FileZilla can upload files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add user 'ubuntu' to a secondary group `www-data`.

```
usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu
```

Now change ownership to `ubuntu:www-data`

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:www-data /var/www/lifestyledesignpros.com/
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/lifestyledesignpros.com/public_html/wp-content/
```

You could also run the following command so that all the new files created are owned by the group

```
chmod g+s /var/www/lifestyledesignpros.com/public_html/wp-content/
```

If you want to fine-tune your control, you could use [Access Control Lists](https://www.ghacks.net/2010/01/28/further-control-of-linux-files-with-acl/) .

```
sudo setfacl -d -m group:www-data:rw /var/www/lifestyledesignpros.com/public_html/wp-content/
```

Comment: Thanks.Its worked with your first two commands for ownership.

Comment: @CyberAbhay Glad it worked! You can accept/upvote my answer if it was helpful